# Can't use "Back to My Mac" screen sharing using iCloud ID in Lion

Tags: macos, icloud, screen-sharing

Screensharing is broken for me in Lion. In Snow Leopard I connected using mobileme for verification. However since upgrading my machines to Lion and my mobileme ID to iCloud, I'm unable to screenshare using my iCloud ID.

The Mac Mini I'm trying to connect to shows up in my finder. If I select the Mini, hit the "Screen Share" button and "Connect using an Apple ID" which has my icloud (.me) e-mail selected, I try to connect and I get an "Authentication failed" message.

Back to My Mac is turned on in iCloud preferences on both computers. Under Accounts, my iCloud e-mail is associated with the Admin account.

Not sure if this is just a bug that needs to be fixed of if there's something I'm missing here..

Comment: Have you tried going about it without the Apple ID? If you attempt to log in with a local user on the mini are you able to get in via AFP or VNC? I prefer that authentication method anyways. Are you doing this on a local network or remotely?

Comment: If you're doing this remotely, make sure ports 5900 (VNC)  and 548 (AFP) are open on your router.

Comment: What router are you using and who is your ISP?  I know with uVerse Back to My Mac won't work.

Comment: I am using a Time Capsule as my router. I can log-in without the Apple ID if I'm on the network locally but I want to access it when I'm away from home.